# ROS2 node without colcon build

Tags: c++, windows, ros2

I would like to run a ros2 Windows node in another application that cannot be built with Colcon.

Is it possible to develop a ROS2 node using only references to the library and header files without the colcon build process?

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: More info is needed here. Colcon is just a build system that calls underlying `cmake` builds, so it's definitely possible. How is the other application being compiled, though? Is it using Cmake?

Comment: I actualy need to wrap Ros functions in a dll and use it with LabVIEW. I am able to build the dll in visual studio but it crashes when it is called.